# Proof of accommodation for a 6-month job seeker visa in Germany

Tags: visa, germany, accommodation

I have an interview for a job seeker visa to Germany for 6 months at the German embassy in India. I have to show them the proof of accommodation.

- Now how can I have a proof of accommodation for 6 months in advance that long before even the visa is granted?
- Do I have to show them the proof of accommodation for the whole 6 months period or a 2-3 days hotel reservation will suffice?
- Secondly how can I decide the date of my departure before even the visa is granted?

Answer (score 2):

I am also applying for job seeker visa next month. According  to my consultant, it is not necessary to show them accommodation in Germany. The main things for this visa are your qualifications and bank statement. You also need to show them the job experience.